# Windows Phone 8 Back button to go back in WebBrowser

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I made a WebBrowser and it works except the back button after pressing the back button the app closes and does not go back one in history. How can I solve the problem? I found solutions in the internet but they don't seem to work.

```
public MainPage()
{
   this.InitializeComponent();
   this.webBrowser.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.google.com", UriKind.Absolute));
   this.webBrowser.LoadCompleted += webBrowser_LoadCompleted;
   this.webBrowser.NavigationFailed += webBrowser_NavigationFailed;
   this.webBrowser.IsScriptEnabled = true;
}
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
   webBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", "history.go(-1)" );
}
```

P. S.:that is not the whole script but i think the rest is unneccesary if not tell me :)
P. P. S.:I'm new to Windows Phone programing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Web browser is just a control inside the page and pressing the device back button navigates back to the previous page or exits the app if it has only one page. So, you would need to stop page navigation on back key press something like this.

```
 protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel=true;
    }
```

This prevents a backnavigation

Now rest is to go to the previous page which can be done by

```
webBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", "history.go(-1)" );
```

so the event becomes

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Cancel=true;
            webBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", "history.go(-1)" );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do:

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    WB1.InvokeScript("eval", "history.go(-1)");
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

When you override OnBackKeyPress, and you don't perform e.Cancel = true; it will do your code, but will also do what normal BackButton does - NavigateBack, Exit App and so on. But you must remember to leave the User an ability to exit your App or Navigate Back, so it will be more suitable to check some conditions  (e.g. your webbrowser history is not null) and then do e.Canel, otherwise Exit the App.

Comment: They can exit the app by Pressing the Windows button, or not? On the Emulator it works fine, I can't actually test it on a physical device, but I think it's almost the same.

Comment: @szoszk No - they cannot Exit App by Start button - when you click it your App is going to Dormant (or Tombstoned) state. You can return to it, just hit the back button and you will see your App. The Back button MUST provide exitting the App - it's one of Certification requirements.

Comment: Ok, I found it but it must only exit the app on first screen ;) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh184840%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: @szoszk Read also point above: Pressing the Back button must return the app to the previous page or return to any previous page within the back stack.

Comment: It goes back in Histroy, now I am searching for a method to close the app on the root page

Comment: App.Current.Terminate(), but Back Button must exit the App on root Page. You won't pass certification.

Comment: I decided no to implement the back button because it's to complicated :D

Answer (score 0):

To exit the app when you are in the root (so you can approve the cerfitication requirements), and also go back in navigation until you are in the root, try with this

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (MiniBrowser.CanGoBack){
        e.Cancel = true;
        MiniBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", "history.go(-1)");
    }
}
```